# Hey. I'm stuck on this inheritance. I need to do a inheritance that the child have 1 input. Because it's a square. How i do it?

Tags: python, list

> Blockquote I need to inheritance a class with less arguments than the parent
> Blockquote

class Rectangle:
def **init**(self, width, height): #init
self.width = width
self.height = height

```
      def set_width(self):  #just printing
        print("The width is: ", self.width)
 
      def set_height(self):
        print("The height is: ", self.height)

      def get_area(self):  #area
        area = self.width * self.height
        print("The area is: ", area)
      
      def get_perimeter(self): #perimeter
        perimeter = 2 * self.width + 2 * self.height
        print("The perimeter is: ", perimeter)
      
      def get_diagonal(self):  #diagonal
        diagonal = ((self.width ** 2 + self.height ** 2) ** 0.5)
        print("the diagonal of the rectangle is: ", round(diagonal,2))

      def get_picture(self): #getting the shape
        if self.height >= 50 or self.width >= 50:
          print("Picture too big!")
        print("The picture of the rectangle is:")
        for i in range(0,self.height): 
          print("*"*self.width)
          
      def get_amount_inside(self):  #getting the area of the inside of the rectangle
        heightInside = self.height-1
        widthInside = self.width-1
        amountInside = heightInside*widthInside

class Square(Rectangle):     # Here. How i do inheritance with less arguments than the parent
      def __init__(self, side):
         Rectangle.__init__(self, side)
         self.side = side

Rect = Rectangle(5,3)
Sq = Square(6)
Rect.set_width()
Rect.set_height()
Rect.get_area()
Rect.get_perimeter()
Rect.get_diagonal()
Rect.get_picture()
Rect.get_amount_inside()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to do this

```
super(Square, self).__init__(width=side, height=side)
```

instead of

```
Rectangle.__init__(self, side)
```